# converting pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Spark and python. I'm given a dataframe of type pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame and I'm trying to convert to a Pandas data frame.

Tried doing using toPandas(). But it didn't work

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
data = sqlContext.read.text('filename')
df1 = data.toPandas()
```

Error message:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-98675a0d0483> in <module>()
----> 1 data.toPandas()

/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in toPandas(self)
   1964                 raise RuntimeError("%s\n%s" % (_exception_message(e), msg))
   1965         else:
-> 1966             pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)
   1967 
   1968             dtype = {}

/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in collect(self)
    463         [Row(age=2, name=u'Alice'), Row(age=5, name=u'Bob')]
    464         """
--> 465         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
    466             port = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    467         return list(_load_from_socket(port, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))

/opt/spark/python/pyspark/traceback_utils.py in __enter__(self)
     70     def __enter__(self):
     71         if SCCallSiteSync._spark_stack_depth == 0:
---> 72             self._context._jsc.setCallSite(self._call_site)
     73         SCCallSiteSync._spark_stack_depth += 1
     74 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setCallSite'
```

Appreciate any help on this

Comment: Can you check if the column `setCallSite` has any null/missing/corrupt values in your file?

Comment: The data does't have a column named 'setCallSite'.

Comment: might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606059/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-setcallsite

Comment: Thank you. However, I found another approach to convert it to pandas dataframe, which is - I created a temporary SQL table using registerDataFrameAsTable(). Then copied the data to a dataframe using df =sqlContext.sql("select * from tablename). Now, I was able to convert df to pandas using toPandas()